# Проблема с роутами с Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, test-driven-development, capybara

Добрый день. Столкнулся с необъяснимым в Rails и Capybara.
Во вьюхе есть кнопка

```
= link_to t(:add_to_cart), offer_add_to_cart_path(offer), class: 'btn', remote: true, method: :post
```

Вручную все работает. На рабочем компе (Ubuntu) работает. спеки проходят нормально когда в Капибаре делаю

```
click_on t(:add_to_cart)
```

Но на домашнем компе (Mac Os X) спеки падают, почему-то Capybara при клике отправляет GET запрос вместо POST

```
   Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
 ActionController::RoutingError:
   No route matches [GET] "/offers/1/add_to_cart"
```

Как так? Репозиторий удалял и заново клинировал. Gem update делал, js: true в тесте есть.
rails (4.2.1) capybara (2.4.4) capybara-webkit (1.5.0)

Comment: проверьте еще раз роут, контроллер, тест

Comment: На другом компьютере работает. Вручную на этом компьютере, на dev сервере работает. Репозиторий один и тот же.

Comment: Попробуйте обновить Rspec (+ поправить тесты), [тут](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24356007/cannot-submit-form-with-capybara-get-instead-of-post) помогло ))